# Sharing ID3D11Buffer and ID3D12Resource

Tags: textures, gpu, directx-11, direct3d, directx-12

In D3D11/D3D12, Is it at all possible to share an ID3D11Buffer with an ID3D12Resource one way or the other? I know it's possible to share ID3D11Texture2D, but it seems like ID3D11Buffer sharing across API versions is not possible. I see no no valid reasons why it wouldn't be allowed since an ID3D12Resource can represent a buffer as well as a texture2d.

I don't really care what the direction of the sharing is (D3D11 -> D3D12 or D3D12 -> D3D11 is fine). I just need to find a way to share that resource since we have an hybrid application for now, and we don't want to uselessly copy the data. Texture2D doesn't work as width/height and color format don't really make sense for our use case.

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed share resources between Direct3D 11 and Direct3D 12. I do so in the `VideoTexture` sample ([UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/blob/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/VideoTextureUWP12/) version / [PC](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples/Graphics/VideoTexturePC12) version) which you can reference.

- You create the resource in one API.

> If you create the `ID3D12Resource` to share, you need to use `D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED` when creating the resource, and you need to use `D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET | D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_SIMULTANEOUS_ACCESS` in the resource description. For Direct3D 11.1 creating a resource, you need to use `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE` because DirectX 12 only supports the newer "NT handle" model.

- You then obtain the share handle.

> For Direct3D 12, this is done with `CreateSharedHandle` on the Direct3D 12 device. For Direct3D 11.x, you have to query the `IDXGIResource1` interface in order to call this method.

- You then use the shared handle to create the resource instance in the other API.

> For Direct3D 11.x sharing a resource created by DirectX 12, use `OpenSharedResource1`. For DirectX 12, use `OpenSharedResource`.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d12/direct3d-12-with-direct3d-11--direct-2d-and-gdi).